# using iMac (2014) as Display for pc source

Tags: imac, hdmi, pc, display

I have got iMac (2014 model), which I want to use as external display for my windows laptop. Is is possible? if yes, how?

I have got a male-to-male mini-display to hdmi connector. But when I connect both my iMac & pc, and I press command+F2 on my iMac nothing happens.

I'm struggling to get Target Display Mode enabled on my iMac, but it doesn't do any thing when I press command + F2. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
vj